# return from __import__() in python

Tags: python, import

So I have a script running as a service, which calls other test scripts.
It identifies the scripts to be executed by parsing a txt file (features.txt) which contains a list of scripts.

In my service "startservice.py" I use the `__import__()` feature to run the necessary test scripts.

Earlier I used to call the script directly using `subprocess.call()`, and read the return value from the script using the `sys.exit(x)` to know if the script executed successfully or with errors by reading the return of `subprocess.call`.

Now with the use of `__import__` function `sys.exit()` directly exits my service.
How can the scripts exit in case of exception/errors and return to the main service?

PS: my first question on stackoverflow. apologize if I'm not being clear.

Comment: You could wrap the import it in a try/except.  But why do you want to use `__import__` instead of calling the other script as a subprocess?

Comment: It seems like the other scripts should have a function (e.g. `main()`) that should get called and _return_ the value to the caller.  This way, you would `return_value = __import__(whatever).main()`.  Of course, that sets some additional constraints on the external script, but ...

Comment: I would like to bundle all the scripts as a single executable, so that users may not have to install python packages on their PC which are imported within my scripts(I use py2exe). However when I use subprocess, the service still looks for the scripts, and runs them are python modules. By using __import__ I understand that the test scripts themselves will be bundled within the executable, along with its dependencies. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @mdameenh, ...I'm not sure how any of what you're describing above argues against the approach mgilson suggested. Having an import operation have substantial side effects is going to be surprising to people who read your code, and structuring it that way (with executable contents at module level rather than encapsulated in a function) means some static checkers won't work with your code -- also that you can't separate the process of importing it from the process of running it, which is often a useful distinction.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with `py2exe`, but I imagine that it generally looks for `import` statements to figure out what to include.  I would _guess_ that it doesn't know how to resolve what `__import__` actually imports when it's pulling everything dynamically (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree with mgilson's approach. I was replying to BrenBarn's question, as to why I'm using __import__ instead of using subprocess.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha; that makes sense. BTW, if you still want to be able to run these scripts directly without the harness, consider the practice of having `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` at the end -- that way the main function will automatically run when invoked as a script, but not when imported.